# .css make the width of an unsorted list to the widht of its parent div

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Hi I have a responsive Dropwdown menu:

```
<div class="main-nav">

<ul id="menu-horizontalnav" class="menu">
   <li <a> </a> </li>
   <li <a> </a> </li>
   <li <a> </a> </li>

</ul>

</div>
```

[image]

The size of the `main-nav` is smaller than the size if the `ul`. 
See the red box in the picture above. The .css parameter for the ul is

```
.js .main-nav .menu {

position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
top: 30px;
width: 100%;
}
```

If somebody could help me get it to work that the width of the 2 elements aligns i would be very happy.

Comment: You should give us all relevant code. But my guess would be the bottom part (`li`) has padding or the border.

Comment: This is just an observation, but I would recommend closing your li start tags. <li>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks `width` is not including the `border`

Add `box-sizing:border-box` for the element on which `border` is given it will fix it, which will give `padding`, `border` from inside without extending the `width`